# TexStudio contents in pdf viewer

Tags: texstudio

I recently started using TexStudio and it is a huge improvement over the experience with TexMaker. I have a question regarding the pdf viewer. At some point I closed the panel which holds the table of contents of the pdf, and I can't seem to get it back.

Where can I find the setting regarding the hide/show panel of contents in the TexStudio pdf viewer? (my operating system is xubuntu)

---

Thank you Torbjørn T. for your answer. To justify posting this simple question, here is a screenshot of the menu I have, with the Show menu arrow barely visible.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the viewer window go to Window --> Show --> Contents.

[image]

Comment: OK, that was simple enough. The thing is that on my computer, the arrow showing that there is a menu at Show is barely visible.

Comment: @BeniBogosel: That depends on your Desktop/UI Theme.

Comment: @TimHoffmann: I realized that now and changed it to avoid further similar issues. :)

Comment: Is it just me, or this option must be marked every time I start the program?

Comment: @G.Bay No idea, I don't use TeXstudio.